# cast two separate columns which has hour ( datatype number) and minutes ( datatype number) to time datatype and subtract 90 minutes in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two separate columns for hours and minutes in my table and I have a report where i should be subtracting 90 minutes from total time put together or ( 1 hour from hour field) and 30 minutes from minutes field. The output can be in minutes or hours.

I tried        `"to_char ( hours_column -1,'00' ) || ':' || to_char ( minutes_column -30,'00' ) AS "MAX_TIME" "` - this fails when I have time like 9:00 I get 8:-30 as the output when I need to get 7:30.

I came up with some sql code with DATEADD and cast functions which worked but it fails when I implement it in Oracle.

`Select Substring(Cast(DATEADD(minute, -90, Cast(hourscolumn + ':' + minutes column as Time)) as varchar(20)),1,5) as max_time`

Can someone help me to implement the above code in Oracle? I'm just trying to deduct 90 minutes by putting the hours and minutes columns together.

Comment: Do the hours and minutes represent a time of day, or an elapsed time? (Either way, why are they stored like that?)

Comment: Oracle does not have a `TIME` data type. The closest you will get is `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`.

Comment: @AlexPoole stored as Numbers. No idea why they designed it that way. They exist as numbers in the table. since the end clients want a report they want to see them together and have 1 hour and 30 minutes subtracted for a field.

Comment: @RyanSchaefer Noted. My first post here.

Comment: @sree - that hasn't answered my main query. If they are a time of day, what if the starting time is before 01:30? If an elapsed time what if that is less than 90 minutes? Can it be more than 24 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

- `test` CTE represents your data. How come you got that (bad) idea? Who/what prevents you from storing 32 hours and 87 minutes into those columns?
- query itself contains

  - `time`: the way you create a valid `date` value. It'll fail if `hours` and/or `minutes` are invalid (such as previously mentioned `32:87`)
  - `subtracted`: subtract `90` minutes from `time`; `(24 * 60)` represents `24` hours in a day, `60` minutes in an hour. It'll contain both date and time component
  - the final `result` is achieved by applying `to_char` with appropriate format mask (`hh24:mi`) to the `subtracted` value

---

```
SQL> alter session set nls_Date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (hours, minutes) as
  2    (select '09', '00' from dual union all
  3     select '23', '30' from dual union all
  4     select '00', '20' from dual
  5    )
  6  select hours,
  7         minutes,
  8         to_date(hours||minutes, 'hh24mi') time,
  9         --
 10         to_date(hours||minutes, 'hh24mi') - 90 / (24 * 60) subtracted,
 11         --
 12         to_char(to_date(hours||minutes, 'hh24mi') - 90 / (24 * 60), 'hh24:mi') result
 13  from test;

HO MI TIME             SUBTRACTED       RESUL
-- -- ---------------- ---------------- -----
09 00 01.07.2019 09:00 01.07.2019 07:30 07:30
23 30 01.07.2019 23:30 01.07.2019 22:00 22:00
00 20 01.07.2019 00:20 30.06.2019 22:50 22:50

SQL>
```

Comment: This does not work if the hours is greater than 23.

Comment: You're welcome. As I said, it works for valid values, @MT0.

Comment: @Littlefoot Any work around if the hours are greater than 23 ?  Last week it was working fine and today i get the ORA-01850: hours must be between 0 and 23 error.

Comment: @Littlefoot getting wrong data when hours are 0,1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NUMTODSINTERVAL` to convert the hours and minutes to `INTERVAL` data types and then you can subtract `INTERVAL '90' MINUTE` and `EXTRACT` the resulting hour and minute components.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( hours_column, minutes_column ) AS
  SELECT  0,  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  1, 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  2, 45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  3,  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 27, 59 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT( HOUR   FROM time ) + EXTRACT( DAY FROM time ) * 24 AS hours,
       EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM time ) AS minutes,
       time,
       TO_CHAR( EXTRACT( HOUR   FROM time ) + EXTRACT( DAY FROM time ) * 24, '00' )
       || ':' || TO_CHAR( ABS( EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM time ) ), 'FM00' ) AS as_string
FROM   (
  SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL( hours_column, 'HOUR' )
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL( minutes_column, 'MINUTE' )
         - INTERVAL '90' MINUTE AS time
  FROM   table_name
)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> HOURS | MINUTES | TIME                          | AS_STRING
> ----: | ------: | :---------------------------- | :--------
>    -1 |     -30 | -000000000 01:30:00.000000000 | -01:30   
>     0 |       0 | +000000000 00:00:00.000000000 |  00:00   
>     1 |      15 | +000000000 01:15:00.000000000 |  01:15   
>     1 |      30 | +000000000 01:30:00.000000000 |  01:30   
>    26 |      29 | +000000001 02:29:00.000000000 |  26:29
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fa56b1adf86b18ef97c89a5cb042ee03)*