# to_date function gives out oracle ORA 01850 : Hour should be between 0 and 23 error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have hour and minute column in my table stored as datatype number. I'm trying to deduct 90 mins by converting them to valid date format and using to_char converting them to valid time format. I get the mentioned error.

I realized that this error is coming for data where i have hours entered as single number. for example 9 instead of 09. I tried LPAD but did not work as int or number doesn't take a 0 when padding.

```
 to_char(to_date ( "hour_column" ||  "minute_column", 'hh24mi' ) - 90 / (24 * 60), 'hh24:mi') AS "Max_TIME"
```

> Ora 08150: hour should be between 0 and 23.

Comment: The above code works fine for hour > 9.

Comment: Can you post a sample with which the error occurs?

Comment: @stickybit When hour has any values from 0 to 9 this doesn't work. It would have worked if my data existed in a two digit format like 00 or 09. Also, i get wrong output for hour = 0 and hour = 1. I'm not sure if i can post a screenshot in comments. New to stack overflow. Hope i'm clear.

Comment: I don't see the problem using `lpad()`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=59adc81da908b73b104f824d3e99803f

Comment: i guess in OP's oracle version lpad may not be supported

Comment: Please update your question to add in sample data and expected results along with the results you get which are wrong. Your example works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5de49c6ae18e2b79c7d65a1f7f218d57

Comment: Op's query is similar to his previous query. There's no standardization in the format the data comes always result indeed is error each time new data comes

Comment: Op's previous query :Possible duplicate of [cast two separate columns which has hour ( datatype number) and minutes ( datatype number) to time datatype and subtract 90 minutes in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57209727/cast-two-separate-columns-which-has-hour-datatype-number-and-minutes-dataty)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a FORMAT adding leading zeroes, e.g.

```
to_char(to_date ( to_char("hour_column" * 100 + "minute_column", '0000'), 'hh24mi' ) - 90 / (24 * 60), 'hh24:mi') AS "Max_TIME"
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to convert a one- or two-digit number to a two-digit string (with leading zeros, if necessary) is with the `TO_CHAR()` function, with the proper format model. The format model `'00'` is what you need; but that model will generate a three character string, leaving a space for the algebraic sign (plus is omitted by default, space is used as placeholder; if the number were negative, you would see the minus sign). Add the `fm` format model modifier to get just the two-digit number without a leading space.

Try to read the solution below step by step; with some luck, you will understand it all in a single reading. The `WITH` clause is there to generate some test inputs (it's not part of the solution!)

Final note - get in the habit of NOT using case-sensitive column names, which require double-quotes. Name your columns whatever you like, without double-quotes; then the names are not case sensitive, and you can write them in lower case, upper case, whatever, in your queries that need to reference them. If you name them with double-quotes, then you must always reference them in double quotes AND remember the exact capitalization you used when you created the table. Good luck remembering that `"Max_TIME"` was written in that capitalization!

```
with
  test_data("hour_column", "minute_column") as (
    select  3, 45 from dual union all
    select 23, 50 from dual union all
    select  1, 15 from dual union all
    select  1, 30 from dual union all
    select  0,  0 from dual
  )
select "hour_column", "minute_column",
       to_char( to_date( to_char("hour_column"  , 'fm00') ||
                         to_char("minute_column", 'fm00') , 'hh24mi') 
                - interval '90' minute
              , 'hh24:mi') as "Max_TIME"
from   test_data
;

hour_column minute_column Max_TIME
----------- ------------- --------
          3            45 02:15
         23            50 22:20
          1            15 23:45
          1            30 00:00
          0             0 22:30
```

If you like hacks, here's a hack - do an arithmetic computation with minutes (add one full day and then take modulo 24 * 60, to get the correct result when the input time is before 01:30) and then apply `substr()` to an interval data type. `WITH` clause and output not shown (they are the same as above).

```
select "hour_column", "minute_column", 
       substr( numtodsinterval(
                 mod((24 + "hour_column") * 60 + "minute_column" - 90, 24 * 60)
                 , 'minute') , 12, 5) as "Max_TIME"
from   test_data
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the [INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#i78291) Data Type rather than separate columns for hour and minute. If you cannot change the data type in your table then the solution could be

```
"hour_column" * INTERVAL '1' HOUR + "minute_column" * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
```

or

```
NUMTODSINTERVAL("hour_column", 'hour') + NUMTODSINTERVAL("minute_column", 'minute')
```

Then you can run your arithmetic, for example

```
("hour_column" * INTERVAL '1' HOUR + "minute_column" * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE) - INTERVAL '90' MINUTE AS "Max_TIME"
```

This solution works also for Hours > 23 or Minutes > 59

Comment: The OP didn't say it outright, but judging both on the inputs and the attempted query, the intent is to model "time of day" in hh24:mi format or equivalent (both for the input and the output). **If** that is correct, then the approach you propose won't work; as an interval, 1:20 minus 90 minutes is simply interval -10 minute, rather than 23:50, the desired result. If you try to fix this you will likely end up with something very close to the hack at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
       SELECT  
      to_date(to_char(case when 
       hour_column<10 
       then '0'||hour_column else 
         hour_column end ||
       "minute_column", 'hh24mi' ) - 90 / 
       (24 * 60), 'hh24:mi') AS "Max_TIME"
       from table
```

Comment: No. I do not want a 0 when hour < 10. When hour < 10 i want a 0 ( single zero) padded to the hour value on the left. For example if hour = 9 it should take in 09. I tried LPAD but no use since the datatype of column is a number.  OR any other way to deduct 90 minutes from the hour and minute columns put together. currently i have them as two different columns stored as numbers.  Hope i'm clear.

Comment: check now if it works i forgot to add hour in case with 0

Comment: Getting an error Ora-00932: Inconsistent data types error. Expected char got number.

Comment: typo forgot to add qoutes in 0 can check now